# $this->setTable() does not work in Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I want to change table name to given string in the constructor in model. The code below is what I tried, but it seems not working.

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

**Model**

```
class Custom extends Model
{
protected $guarded = ['id', 'ct'];

const UPDATED_AT = null;
const CREATED_AT = 'ct';

public function __construct(array $attributes = [], string $tableName = null) {

    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->setTable($tableName);
}

}
```

**Controller**

```
$tableName = 'some string';
$custom = new Custom([], $tableName);
$result = $custom->create($data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only passing one parameter on the constructor function, but it expects 2 params. So, either pass two param, or make the constructor like this-

```
public function __construct($table = null, $attr = [])
{
    $this->setTable($table);
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

But I don't understand why would you do that? The standard practice is create one model per table. You should do that either.

Comment: I ended up creating one model per table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Model::create method. This is magical shenanigans via [Model::__call](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/95407bd01c23003d52236aeb078f557bdabbade7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1464). Calling `$custom->create(...)` will forward the call to [Builder::create](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/95407bd01c23003d52236aeb078f557bdabbade7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L750) which calls [Builder::newModelInstance](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/95407bd01c23003d52236aeb078f557bdabbade7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L1062), which in turns calls [Model::newInstance](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/95407bd01c23003d52236aeb078f557bdabbade7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L285). This code does not know about the original model at all, it only knows about the `$data` attributes. (It is usually called in a static context, like `Model::create(...)`, without an origin instance.)

The easiest workaround for you would be to create a new class deriving from Custom, and have it declare the $table property. This would require one model per table.

```
class Custom2 extends Custom {
    public $table = 'some string';
}
```